# R function krige.cv() returns NAs

Tags: r, kriging, cross-validation

I recently completed a geostatistics course, and now trying to apply my knewly acquired knowledge to a real case.
I have a dataset with 2 122 groundwater level measurement points. I would like to extrapolate them into a raster map. The previous group that worked on this matter used some inverse distance weighting. But I thought kriging might make more sense. Which is why I decided to try it out and perform some LOOCV to compare methods.
I do not have any NA in the original dataset, but when using function krige.cv(), I get 85 NAs. This messes up with computing zscore statistics.
I would like to know why I have these NA values, and whether it is fine to simply remove them.

This is my call of the function:

```
GLGkrige1 <- krige.cv(GLG~1, ground_water_points, model=vgmGLG, nmax=100)
```

And this is the summary of the result:

```
Object of class SpatialPointsDataFrame
Coordinates:
                min       max
coords.x1  4.749619  5.017867
coords.x2 52.289492 52.425470
Is projected: NA 
proj4string : [NA]
Number of points: 2122
Data attributes:
   var1.pred          var1.var         observed         residual            zscore               fold       
 Min.   :-5.2735   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :-5.630   Min.   :-1.77453   Min.   :-25624692   Min.   :   1.0  
 1st Qu.:-1.9587   1st Qu.:0.2195   1st Qu.:-2.040   1st Qu.:-0.12146   1st Qu.:        0   1st Qu.: 531.2  
 Median :-0.8083   Median :0.2301   Median :-0.810   Median : 0.00069   Median :        0   Median :1061.5  
 Mean   :-1.3896   Mean   :0.2390   Mean   :-1.463   Mean   : 0.00135   Mean   :        0   Mean   :1061.5  
 3rd Qu.:-0.4698   3rd Qu.:0.2467   3rd Qu.:-0.460   3rd Qu.: 0.12386   3rd Qu.:        0   3rd Qu.:1591.8  
 Max.   : 0.7157   Max.   :1.7875   Max.   : 1.590   Max.   : 3.55142   Max.   : 25624692   Max.   :2122.0  
 NA's   :85        NA's   :85                        NA's   :85         NA's   :85
```

I just noticed that my first run on the krige.cv() where I forgot to set a nmax has 1488 NAs, so I suspect this has to do with the nmax.

Could these be points that do not have enough neighbours?

---

The problem came from two points sharing the same coordinates (and different values). Now everything is running smoothly again.

Comment: You could try plotting those points to see if they are exceptional in some way? `plot(GLGkrige1, col=1+is.na(GLGkrige1$var1.pred),pch=19)` might work to show the NA points in red...

Comment: I could not get `krige.cv` to return NA predictions on the `meuse` data set no matter how I tweaked `nmax`.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, they are all located in the same area. Although not all points in that area result in NAs. I tried tweaking nmax. The smaller the nmax, the lower the number of NAs, it seems. However, I still get 9 NAs with nmax=10 (and I think this is a low value already).

Comment: I asked a teacher for help, and he found the source of the problem: two points had the same coordinates. I will edit the question. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Please write answers to questions into the area reserved for answers and not into the question.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I finally posted the answer. And thank you for the edit!

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from two points sharing the same coordinates (and different values). With one of these points removed, everything is running smoothly again.